# LaTeX beginner's tutorial

Tags: tutorials

I was recently introduced to LaTeX but I cannot find any resources online for beginners like me. I need a how-to kind of a resource for basic functionality. Pardon my vagueness. I currently have no knowledge of it but I am willing to learn.

Comment: `But I cannot find any resources online for beginners like me` see this question which would help http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-is-the-best-book-to-start-learning-latex "What is the best book to start learning LaTeX?"

Comment: I recommend the series from [Dickimaw LaTeX Books](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex) (also as [dickimaw on CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/dickimaw)).

Comment: It really depends on exactly what you want to use TeX for.  Will you be report writing, making presentations, writing a novel etc.?  If you could provide some context/specific examples that would be very helpful.  But here are a couple of useful links [LaTeX for Complete Novices](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/) and [Latex Thesis](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&ved=0CEkQFjAF&url=http%3A%2F%2Fnats-www.informatik.uni-hamburg.de%2Fpub%2FUser%2FLaTeXNovember%2Fthesis_a4.pdf&ei=8woGU_aQNLO10QW4qYGoAw&usg=AFQjCNFxrEd6aIHYPB5v68c9QxFR7SAwxA)

Comment: I would still call this a duplicate of Q11, but keep an eye on http://www.github.com/vermiculus/texample; it's aimed to be a compendium of actual examples (similar to TeXample.net's TikZ examples; no official affiliation).

Answer (score 5):

“the latex companion” has already been mentioned; it’s a good book, but i don’t think of it as a introduction.  it is also online at [the publisher’s site](http://www.informit.com/store/latex-companion-9780133387667)

for a beginner online text, i regularly recommend “a short introduction to latex”, which is available in lots of languages — the english version is [on ctan (the tex materials archive)](http://mirror.ctan.org://info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf)

finally, [the tex faq](http://texfaq.org/FAQ-man-latex) has a rambling list of such stuff.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the reference book mentioned by Yuan Ma, `The LaTeX Companion`, you'll find many `online` resources at [www.tug.org](http://www.tug.org/interest.html#latextutorials) and on this [page](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/dickimaw.html) of The TeX Catalogue on line.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation for textbook is "The Latex Companion", this is a really good book for you to learn LaTex, no matter you are the beginner or already have a lot of experience.
[Amazon link is here:](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201362996)

Answer (score 0):

How To Tex has a fine collection of important topics, refer to "[12 great resources for getting started with latex](http://www.howtotex.com/general/12-great-resources-for-getting-started-with-latex/)", note the sections "Tutorials and Guides" and "LaTeX installation". If you are interested in mathematics [there](http://www.ams.jhu.edu/~ers/learn-latex/) is an entry example with all the necessary files and some good links.

... and use the search function on this page.

Comment: The first link is dead/broken, and won't return here if visited.